# Tkinter: How to make one button with multiple text fields?

Tags: python, tkinter, button, text

I have this table in `tkinter`. However, I want to have only one button in each row with four text fields. (I currently have four buttons in each row.)

Basically, I want to connect these four buttons to one button in a row. How can I do this?

```
from tkinter import *

class Table:
  
    def __init__(self,root):
      
        # code for creating table
        for i in range(total_rows):
            for j in range(total_columns):
              
                self.e = Button(root, width=20,text = lst[i][j])
              
                self.e.grid(row=i, column=j)

# take the data
lst = [(1,'Raj','Mumbai',19),
       (2,'Aaryan','Pune',18),
       (3,'Vaishnavi','Mumbai',20),
       (4,'Rachna','Mumbai',21),
       (5,'Shubham','Delhi',21)]

# find total number of rows and
# columns in list
total_rows = len(lst)
total_columns = len(lst[0])

# create root window
root = Tk()
t = Table(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: If you could connect four buttons to one, what action would that button perform?

Comment: This super button will be for editing the row. For example to change names, ages....If you know how to make one button with multiple text(with names, ages, birthdays...) you can post the code.

Comment: So you could make a super button connected to a function that would control the attributes of a specific number of other objects (buttons, labels, etc)

Comment: Ok but i dont know how to do it.

Comment: I think I have something that might work. I'll post it when I find it.

Comment: ok post it then pls

Comment: I'll post updated code that is almost complete (doesn't save table)

Comment: Just combine the four items in each row into a single string and create a button with this string.

Answer (score 0):

I've modified your code to include a `Toplevel` window called 'work' that gives access to the super buttons. The quantity of buttons is determined by the number of rows in table.

Each button is connected to another `Toplevel` window called 'edit'.

'Edit' contains `Label`, `Entry` and `Button` objects. The quantity is determined by the number of columns in table.

All windows are resizable with 'work' and 'edit' windows accessible via F1 key.

Escape key will close 'top' table via `messagebox`.

Ok this is the latest version.

I've divided the project into two python files, a data file called 'Datafile.py' and code called "Records.py'.

'Datafile.py' must be saved separately from 'Records.py.

Records code is completely configurable by changing table data in Datafile.py

Changing table data by adding or modifying columns and/or rows will configure the main program. The table, work and edit windows are determined by the row and columns in Datafile.py

SAVE THIS AS 'Datafile.py'

```py
import time

timedate = time.localtime()
year = timedate.tm_year

indice = [ "gender", "name", "location", "age", "birth"]
table = [
    ["Male",   "Raj",      "Mumbai",   19, year-19],
    ["Male",   "Aaryan",   "Pune",     18, year-18],
    ["Female", "Vaishnavi","Mumbai",   20, year-20],
    ["Female", "Rachna",   "Mumbai",   21, year-21],
    ["Male",   "Shubham",  "Delhi",    21, year-21],
    ["Male",   "Roger",    "New York", 17, year-17],
    ["Male",   "David",    "Sydney",   53, year-53],
    ["Female", "Jennifer", "London",   42, year-42]]
```

Here is the main program 'Records.py'.

SAVE AS 'Records.py'

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
from Datafile import timedate, indice, table

class Table:

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = root
        self.master.title("Table")
        # create table of buttons in self.store
        self.rows = len(table)
        self.columns = len(table[0])
        # number of rows and columns
        self.store = []
        for r in range(self.rows):
            self.store.append([])
            for c in range(self.columns):
                e = tk.Label(
                    self.master, width = 20, bd = 1,
                    relief = "raised", text = table[r][c])
                e.grid(row = r, column = c, sticky = tk.NSEW)
                self.flexx(self.master, r = r, c = c)
                self.store[r].append(e) # all table buttons stored in list
        self.master.geometry(f"{self.columns*100}x{self.rows*26}")
        self.master.update()

        # create toplevel widget for buttons
        self.work = tk.Toplevel(self.master)
        self.work.transient(self.master)
        self.work.withdraw()
        self.work.title("Individual Selector")
        # populate toplevel widget with the Super buttons
        # make buttons resizable
        for r in range(self.rows):
            e = tk.Button(
                self.work, text = f"{table[r][1]}", bd = 1,
                command = self.redirect(self.access, r))
            e.grid(row=r, column=0, sticky = tk.NSEW)
            self.flexx(self.work, r = r)
        # Table edit window
        self.edit = tk.Toplevel(self.master)
        self.edit.transient(self.master)
        self.edit.withdraw()
        self.edit.title("Table Editor")
        self.labelframe = tk.LabelFrame(self.edit, labelanchor = tk.N, text = "Name")
        self.labelframe.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = tk.NSEW)
        self.flexx(self.edit)
        # place entry tools here
        self.data = []
        for c in range(self.columns):
            l = tk.Label(self.labelframe, text = f"{indice[c]}")
            l.grid(row = c, column = 0, sticky = tk.NSEW)
            e = tk.Entry(self.labelframe)
            e.grid(row = c, column = 1, sticky = tk.NSEW)
            self.data.append(e)
            b = tk.Button(
                self.labelframe, text = "Enter", bd = 1,
                command = self.redirect(self.change, c))
            b.grid(row = c, column = 2, sticky = tk.NSEW)
            self.flexx(self.labelframe, r = c, c = 1)
        # wire up master and work widgets
        for a, b in [(self.master, self.closer),
                     (self.work, self.opener),
                     (self.edit, self.editor)]:
            a.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', b)
            a.bind("<KeyRelease-Escape>", b)
        # Keys to work widget
        self.master.bind("<F1>", self.opener)
        self.work.bind("<F1>", self.opener)
        self.edit.bind("<F1>", self.editor)

    def redirect(self, f, *args):
        return lambda: f(*args)

    def flexx(self, m, r = 0, c = 0, rw = 1, cw = 1):
        m.rowconfigure( r, weight = rw )
        m.columnconfigure( c, weight = cw )

    def change(self, c):
        e = self.data[c]
        self.store[self.currentRow][c]["text"] = e.get()
        table[self.currentRow][c] = e.get()

    def closer(self, ev = None):
        if messagebox.askquestion(title = "Quit", message = "Confirm",
                                  detail = "Close program?") == "yes":
            self.master.destroy()

    def opens( self, o, m ):
        """Toggle switch for toplevel"""
        if o.winfo_viewable( ):
            o.withdraw( )
            m.focus_set( )
        else:
            o.focus_set( )
            o.deiconify()

    def position(self, o):
        x = int(o.winfo_x() + o.winfo_width() + 5)
        y = int(o.winfo_y() + o.winfo_height() / 2)
        return x, y

    def opener(self, ev = None):
        x, y = self.position( self.master)
        self.work.geometry(f"190x{26*self.rows}+{x}+{y}")        
        self.opens(self.work, self.master)

    def editor(self, ev = None):
        x, y = self.position( self.work)
        self.edit.geometry(f"213x{26*self.columns}+{x}+{y}")
        self.opens(self.edit, self.work)

    def access(self, *args):
        self.currentRow = r = args[0]
        self.labelframe["text"] = f"{table[r][1]}"
        for i,e in enumerate(self.data):
            e.delete(0, "end")
            e.insert(0, table[r][i])
        self.editor()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    top = Table(root)
    root.mainloop()
```